# Polynomial relation between unitary operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a unitary operator in finite-dimensional vector space. Show that for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ there is unitary operator $g$ such that $g^m=f$. Moreover, we can find it as a polynomial  $g=P(f)$, where $P$ is polynomial.

**My proof:** Since $f$ is unitary operator then there is an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ such that matrix of operator $f$ in this basis is diagonal, i.e. $$A_f=\text{diag}(e^{i\phi_1},\dots, e^{i\phi_n}).$$ Then if we define an operator $g$ with matrix on this basis as $$A_g=\text{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\dots, e^{i\theta_n}),$$ where $\theta_k=\dfrac{\phi_k}{m}$, then it follows that $g^m=f$ and it is not so difficult to show that $g$ is unitary operator because $|g(x)|=|x|$ for any $x\in V$.

Suppose that $\text{Sp}(f)=\{e^{i\phi_1},\dots,e^{i\phi_k}\}$ - distinct eigenvalues of $f$ then $\{e^{i\theta_1},\dots,e^{i\theta_k}\}$ are distinct eigenvalues of $g$. My goal is to construct a polynomial $P(f)$  s.t.  $P(f)=g$, i.e. $P(f)(e_i)=g(e_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Let's start with the following step: Consider the following polynomial of operator $$Q_1(f)=e^{i\theta_1}\dfrac{\prod \limits_{r=1,r\neq1}^{k}(f-e^{i\phi_r}\cdot \text{id})}{\prod \limits_{r=1,r\neq1}^{k}(e^{i\phi_1}-e^{i\phi_r})}$$
and we see it makes sense because denominator does not vanish. One can show that $Q_1(f)(e_j)=e^{i\theta_1}e_j=g(e_j),$ if $e_j$ corresponds to eigenvalue $e^{i\phi_1}$ and $Q_1(f)(e_j)=0$ for otherwise. Then if we take polynomial $P(f)=\sum \limits_{p=1}^{k}Q_k(f)$ then this is the desired polynomial.

Is my solution and reasoning correct? Would be very grateful for any comments and help, please!

I know that probably my solution is quite cumbersome but I was not able to come up with smith more trivial.

Comment: Do you know about polynomial interpolation?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I do know Lagrange interpolation polynomial. I was not able to apply Lagrange interpolation directly to my problem but I came up with smth similar which I posted above. But if you have something useful to post I'd more than happy to read it!

Comment: @RobertIsrael, is my solution correct?

Comment: In a typical setting, all you really need to state (without proof) is that there exists a polynomial $p$ for which $p(e^{i\phi_k}) = e^{i \theta_k}$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. That said, your proof is completely correct.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yeah you are right. I did not think in this way, I was thinking about polynomial of operators. But I really like your way. Indeed, if we can find such polynomial $p$ as you wrote then $p(f)(e_k)=e^{i\theta_k}e_k=g(e_k)$ which means that $p(f)=g$ and we are done. Nice! Thanks a lot for help! :)