# Unitary matrix as a product of real orthogonal and complex symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Show that any unitary matrix $U$ can be written as a product of real orthogonal matrix and complex symmetric matrix.

*Hint:* For any unitary matrix $A$ and for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is unitary matrix $B$ such that $B^n=A$. (I proved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603774/polynomial-relation-between-unitary-operators?noredirect=1#comment7407696_3603774))

**My attempt:** Since $U$ is unitary then $U^TU$ is also unitary matrix then by hint one can find unitary matrix $X$ such that $X^2=U^TU$. Then I stucked and don't know how to proceed.

Would be thankful if someone can show how to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you decide that you should look for a matrix $X$ with $X^2 = U^TU$? It's the correct idea, so I'm curious as to how you thought of it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, first of let me express my gratitude for your permanent help in my linear algebra questions! I really appreciate it. To be honest I was thinking on this problem from early morning. First of all I was working with matrix $U$ but I noticed that it does not give nothing useful. Then I consider the matrix $U^TU$ which is unitary and   I applied the hint, namely considered the root $X$ of $U^TU$. But then I stucked :) I don't know I am solving problems on linear algebra and most of them I cannot solve which makes me sad :) But I really like this subject :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a unitary matrix with $X^2 = UU^T$, and $X = p(UU^T)$ (for some polynomial $p$).  Note that $X$ must itself be symmetric. Because $X$ commutes with $UU^T$, $X^{-1}$ also commutes with $UU^T$.

We have $U = X \cdot (X^{-1}U)$.  We can see that $X^{-1}U$ is orthogonal as follows:
$$
(X^{-1}U)(X^{-1}U)^T = X^{-1} UU^T X^{-T} = X^{-1}(UU^T) X^{-1} 
\\= (UU^T)X^{-1}X^{-1} = UU^T (UU^T)^{-1} = I.
$$

---

Equivalently, we could have taken $U = (UX^{-1}) \cdot X$, with $X^2 = U^TU$.

Comment: Symmetricity of $X$ follows from $X=p(UU^T)$ and $((UU^T)^k)^T=(UU^T)^k$, right? You showed that $X^{-1}U$ is orthogonal. Also it should be real I guess. We need to show that $\overline{X^{-1}U}=X^{-1}U$. Indeed, $\overline{X^{-1}U}=\overline{X^{-1}}\overline{U}=\overline{X}^{-1}\overline{U}=X^TU^{-t}=XU^{-T}=X^{-1}U$. The last equality follows from $X^2=UU^T$

Comment: The problem is not easy as I thought. It has some tricky steps IMHO. Thanks a lot for your permanent help! I appreciate your answer as the best!

Comment: Glad to help. What I had in mind, by the way, is that a matrix must be real if it is both orthogonal and unitary since $U^T,U^*$ are both the inverse of $U$ and hence equal. I think your version makes a bit more sense though honestly: if we see that the matrix is real and we know that it is unitary, then of course it is orthogonal.

Comment: Please sorry but do you have any idea about this problem? I have shown my attempts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604319/criterion-for-existence-of-orthogonal-operator-with-desired-properties