# Criterion for existence of orthogonal operator with desired properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be euclidean (hermitian) space. The set of vectors $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k\}$ can be mapped under orthogonal operator to the set of vectors $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k\}$  **iff** Gram matrices of each sets are equal, i.e. $$G(a_1,\dots,a_k)=G(b_1,\dots,b_k).$$

It seems to me quite a nice problem. Probably it should not be so difficult and let me show my attempts.

$\Rightarrow$ This is trivial because if the first set can be mapped to the second via orthogonal operator $f$ then $f(a_i)=b_i$ and $(b_i,b_j)=(f(a_i),f(a_j))=(a_i,a_j)$ the last inequality from definition of orthogonal operator $f$. It shows that corresponding elements of matrices $G_a$ and $G_b$ are equal which means that $G(a_1,\dots,a_k)=G(b_1,\dots,b_k).$

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose that $G(a_1,\dots,a_k)=G(b_1,\dots,b_k)$ and let $(e)=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$. Suppose $a_i$ has coordinates $(a^1_i,\dots,a^n_i)$ then $[G_a]_{ij}=(a_i,a_j)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}a^k_ia^k_j=[A^TA]_{ij}$ which means that $G_a=A^TA$ and analogously $G_b=B^TB$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times k$ matrices, whose columns are coordinates of vectors $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ and $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$, respectively. So we have that $A^TA=B^TB$.

My goal is to construct an operator $f:V\to V$ such that its matrix in the orthonormal basis $(e)$ is orthogonal matrix. Let's call this matrix $M_f^{(e)}=M$. As I said $M$ should be orthogonal and $MA=B$.  I was trying to play with $M=BA^T$ or $M=AB^T$ but I failed.

So I would be very grateful if anyone can give useful idea or show the solution, please!

Comment: It has occurred to me that this approach could be made easier if we use either the polar decomposition or the spectral theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Hmm could you show it, please?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934844/ata-btb-is-a-qb-for-some-orthogonal-q) for the approach via the polar decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer for the case that the sets $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ and $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$ are linearly independent (or equivalently, the Grammian matrices are invertible).

Suppose that $G(a_1,\dots,a_k) = G(b_1,\dots,b_k)$.  Let $\{a_{k+1},\dots,a_n\}$ and $\{b_{k+1},\dots,b_n\}$ be orthonormal bases for $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}^\perp$ and $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}^\perp$.  Verify that $G(a_1,\dots,a_n) = G(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.

Note that a linear map $f:V \to V$ is orthogonal if and only if $(f(x),f(y)) = (x,y)$ for all $x,y \in V$.  Show that if we take $f$ to be the unique linear map satisfying $f(a_j) = b_j$ for $j=1,\dots,n$, then $f$ satisfies this property and is therefore orthogonal.

---

An extension of this solution to the general case:

Because $A^TA = B^TB$, we have $\ker A = \ker B$.  It follows that a set of vectors $a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d}$ will be linearly indepnendent if and only if the corresponding set $b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_d}$ is linearly independent.

With that in mind, we can select a set $a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d}$ that forms a basis of $\operatorname{span}(\{a_1,\dots,a_k\})$ (which has dimension $d$).  The corresponding set $b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_d}$ forms a basis for $\operatorname{span}(\{b_1,\dots,b_k\})$.  As before, we select vectors $a_{d+1},\dots,a_{n}$ and $b_{d+1},\dots,b_n$ that form bases for the respective orthogonal complements of the spans.

Now, it suffices to define $f$ to be the linear map satisfying $f(a_{j_\ell}) = b_{j_\ell}$ for $\ell = 1,\dots,d$ and $f(a_\ell) = b_\ell$ for $\ell = d+1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks a lot! I will take a look at this but I guess that I got your idea.

Comment: @ZFR You're welcome! I've extended the proof to the general case now. An alternative approach here is to use something like Gram-Schmidt decomposition or the $QR$ factorizations of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Let me ask you a question: You are solving those problems very easily. OMG. How come? :)

Comment: @ZFR I recently finished my mathematics PhD and defended a thesis that focused on matrix analysis and linear algebra.  I also answer questions like yours on this site in my spare time, and I tend to stick to the linear algebra questions when possible because those are the most appealing to me.  All that is to say: I have a lot of practice.

Comment: Great! I am also Ph.D student but I am on my second year. I had linear algebra in my undergraduate but it was not so advanced course. I am very interested in functional analysis and that's why I have started linear algebra. I am studying it for the last 2 month from the scratch and it is really nice subject :)

Comment: @ZFR Which text are you using?  From your questions, it seems as though you are taking a path that is very different from the one I took.  When I took linear algebra in my first year of graduate school, we used Horn and Johnson's Matrix analysis.

Comment: Hmmm I have never seen this book to be honest which you mentioned. Do you recommend it? I am reading lectures in linear algebra by T.E.Panov (those lectures are on Russian).

Comment: @ZFR It's good as a reference and has a very good collection of exercises, but honestly I don't think that it matters so much exactly where you start.  Especially with the existence of the internet, if you have a professor that tells you what you need to know any reasonable set of notes is fine.  If Russian is your first language, it makes sense that you would start with texts that are written in Russian.

Comment: Yeah you are right! Russian is my native language :) BTW I got your solution. Really tricky. I was so far from correct reasoning :)

Comment: Let me ask you one more question: The vectors $\{a_{d+1},\dots,a_n\}$ which you took to be orthonormal basis of $\langle a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d}\rangle ^{\perp}$ have not nothing in common with our initial vectors $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$, right? By definition of $f$ we see that $f(a_{j_p})=b_{j_p}$. But we need to show that $f$ maps $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ to $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$. What if $p$ such that $1\leq p\leq k$ s.t. $a_p\notin \{a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d}\}$ and $a_p\in \langle a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d} \rangle$ how it follows that $f(a_p)=b_p$? I have difficulties with that.

Comment: @ZFR Whoops!  That's right; a poor choice of notation I guess. In any case I'm adding $n-d$ vectors so that we have a basis of $V$.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Anyway it does not mater. But how it follows that $f$ maps $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ to $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$? Did you get my point?

Comment: @ZFR The key point is that $A$ and $B$ have the same kernel.  If $a_k$ can be produced as a linear combination of $a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_d}$, then the corresponding linear combination of $b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_d}$ produces $b_k$.

Comment: Ohh yeah. Exactly! Really neat! Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry but could you help me with this question, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607296/canonical-form-and-basis-of-orthogonal-operator?noredirect=1#comment7414927_3607296

Comment: I think that your answer should clarify all my thoughts :)