# Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices in $M_{n,p}(R)$. Show that $A^{T}A = B^{T}B \iff \exists P \in On(R)$ such that $B = PA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

let A and B two matrices in $Mn,p(R)$ show that $A^T$$A$=$B^T$$B$ if and only if there exist $P$ belong to $On(R)$  s.t  $B$=$PA$.

Comment: Where exactly are you in doubt? Show how much have you worked.

Comment: @Vanyusha Pavlova the inverse implication is easy but the direct I had essay that $A^T$A is symmetric and apply the spectral theorem

Comment: Can you provide definition of $On$? Then I think you are going to get what you want, because there are many notations. And I think is good if you show what you have done, because your question is being down voted. (But it was not me, ok?) I just wanna help you to obtain what you want because of the rules of this site.

Comment: @Vanyusha Pavlova thank you I note On the the set of orthogonal matrices with n*n coefficient

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $A$ and $B$ have "polar decompositions" $A = U_1P_1$ and $B = U_2P_2$, with $U_1,U_2$ orthogonal and $P_1,P_2$ positive semidefinite.

---

Using the spectral theorem:

We can write $U^T(A^TA)U = D$ for some diagonal $D$ and orthogonal $U$. Let $d_1,\dots,d_n$ denote the diagonal entries of $D$. Define $P = AU$ and $Q = BU$. Note that $P^TP = Q^TQ = D$.

Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th column of $P$ and let $q_i$ denote the $i$th column of $Q$.  Using the fact that $P^TP = Q^TQ = D$, we have
$$
p_i^Tp_j = q_i^Tq_j = \begin{cases} d_i & i=j \\ 0 & i \neq j. \end{cases}
$$
Using this, show that there is an orthogonal matrix $V$ for which $Vp_i = q_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$. In other words, $VP = Q$.

Now, show that if $VP = Q$, then $VA = B$.

Comment: please how can prove the polar decomposition in simple manner I don't understand the demo proposed in wikipedia it is difficult

Comment: @Reda What have you established in your course so far? Can we use the existence of singular value decomposition?

Comment: neither SVD if we can use spectral theorem?

Comment: @Reda I do not understand your comment

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: showing the existence of V it's exactly the question I asked below thank you

Comment: @Reda The point is that we have reduced it to an easier case; I'm leaving it to you to handle the rest

Comment: @Reda You can build $V$ using the fact that $p_i^Tp_j$ and $q_i^Tq_j$ are given as in the equation written above

Comment: what I can say is qi form a basis of Rn and also qi this basis are orthogonal so V the matrice of passage between to orthogonal basis will be so is it right ? thank you

Comment: You can only say that $q_i$ forms a basis if all columns $q_i$ are non-zero, which might not be the case.

Comment: @RedaElouasti You could also apply [the proof given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3604319/81360), where we take $a_i$ to be the columns of $A$ and $b_i$ to be the columns of $B$.

Comment: thank you soo much